# How to add a dependency in a multiplatform kotlin / native intellij project?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-native

I have the following build.gradle configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.41'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
kotlin {
    linuxX64("linux") {
        binaries {
            executable {
               entryPoint = 'sample.main'
               runTask?.args('')
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        linuxMain {
            dependencies {
                api("org.http4k:http4k-core:3.183.0")
            }
        }
        linuxTest {
        }
    }
}
```

And the following source file `src/linuxMain/kotlin/sample/SampleLinux.kt` :

```
package sample

fun hello(): String = "Hello, Kotlin/Native!"

fun main() {
    println(hello())
}
```

How to add a external library in order to be able to use autocomplete in imports for the library `org.http4k:http4k-core:3.183.0`?

As you can see, I tried to add the line `api("org.http4k:http4k-core:3.183.0")` in linuxMain dependencies, but although intellij show the library in External Libraries section, I cannot work with the packages neither classes of http4k in `SampleLinux.kt` file: any `org.http4k.....` import attempt is not recognized and generates compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look, I am almost sure that `http4k` is JVM-only library, at least for now. According to [this issue](https://github.com/http4k/http4k/issues/186), they are still waiting for Native to grow. If you are interested, it would be nice if one can ask the library maintainers again. As far as K/N has grown a lot by the last year, maybe they change their mind.